# Save IP in remote host every time connection is up (as non-root-user)

Tags: ssh, root, non-root-user, ssh-agent

I have a dynamic local Lan IP at work (temporarily), but in order to connect from home, I ssh to the host A (static IP) and from there to my machine.

However, since the IP changes, I would like to save in host A frequently, for instance every time the connection is up (I often loose my ethernet connection due to poor cables).

I'm using NetowrkManager so I created a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/90exportIP` which runs the following:

```
 ssh hostA "echo $(date)  enp4s0f2 IP: $(/sbin/ifconfig enp4s0f2 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $2}'|sed 's/addr://') >> todaysElanIP";
```

This gets my IP and saves it in file `todaysElanIP` in host A.

The problem is this script is run as root, and my keys are not there. I sometimes just run this command on bash and it works. But I would like it to run automatically every time the network is up.

I tried `runuser -l myUser`, but ssh-agent is not accessible like that.

It doesn't has to work every time. For instance, at boot time I haven't yet added my key to ssh-agent. If next time the network is down and then up again the export happens, that would work for me.

It's a bit confusing how I can easily do something with a non-root user and it seems so hard as root.

Comment: Would you like to perform the `ssh hostA` so you'll be logged in as a regular user instead of `root`?

Comment: @Yaron Yes, I think that would work. It should be my user, because I have ssh agent running with the key to hostA.